# maximize and minimize the function by using Least square in python

Tags: python, pandas, static, least-squares

I am trying to minimize Root mean square error(RMSE) and maximize the Nash efficiency(NSC) by using Least square method in Python. The coding is bit longer and complicated so, I just attached here a flow chart to understand the problem.

In my Model all the parameters are fixed except Lam. As Lam depends on Ln so to calculate Ln I have to apply Threshold in such a way that Ln= Lam-LP

in my case Objective functions are RMSE and NSC and bounds= [1-10]. can anyone explain  me please how should I formulate my coding step wise. Thanks in advance
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnhnJ.png) flowchart:

Comment: Might be better suited to [datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com).